# Linq ToDictionary returns an anonymous type

Tags: linq, dynamic, anonymous-types

I want to call a method that returns an anonymous type.  I need to know what the Type of this anonymous type is because I am returning it in a method.  Is it called "dynamic"?  When I debug, the watch window says the type is <>f__AnonymousType0.

Here is my code:

```
// this doesn't compile
public static Dictionary<int,dynamic> GetRuleNamesDictionary()
{
    List<ResponseRoutingRule> rules = GetResponseRoutingRules();    
    var q = (rules.Select(r => new {r.ResponseRoutingRuleId, r.RuleName}));

    var dict1 = q.ToDictionary(d => d.ResponseRoutingRuleId);
    var dict = q.ToDictionary(d => d.ResponseRoutingRuleId, d => d.RuleName);
    return dict;
}

public static List<ResponseRoutingRule> GetResponseRoutingRules()
{
   ....
}


public class ResponseRoutingRule
{
    public int ResponseRoutingRuleId { get; set; }
    ....
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you actually seem to be returning a `Dictionary<int, string>`. The type of `dict`'s values isn't an anonymous type; it's a plain old `string`. In fact, there doesn't seem to be any need for anonymous types *or* `dynamic` here.

Are you sure this isn't what you really want?

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetRuleNamesDictionary()
{
    return GetResponseRoutingRules()
            .ToDictionary(r => r.ResponseRoutingRuleId, r => r.RuleName);    
}
```

If not, please let us know why.

If you *really* want to stick with `dynamic`, you could of course cast as appropriate:

```
public static Dictionary<int, dynamic> GetRuleNamesDictionary()
{
    return GetResponseRoutingRules()
            .ToDictionary(r => r.ResponseRoutingRuleId, r => (dynamic) r.RuleName);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an object.  If you need strong typing, don't make it anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

What I really want to do is return a dynamic type with 2 properties called `ResponseRoutingRuleId` and `RuleName`.  This is so I can assign it to an MVC select list and specify the `dataValue` field and the `dataText` field.

```
SomeMethod(){
    List<{my dynamic type}> ruleObject = GetRuleObject();

    var ruleSelectList = new Web.Mvc.SelectList (ruleObject, "ResponseRoutingRuleId", "RuleName");
}

List<{my dynamic type}> GetRuleObject(){...}
```

In my Linq query, I am getting this dynamic object but I don't know what return type to specify in `GetRuleObject()`.